# How to open XLS file with pandas

Tags: excel, pandas, xlsx, xls

I'm trying to change the format of an .XLS file to .xlsx, but without success with Pandas until here. The file has the .XLS extension, with a format for windows 97-2003. Solutions like changing the engine to xlrd have already been tested. Does anyone know how to help in this case?

```
import pandas as pd

path = "G:\\documents\\vscode\\company\\test.XLS"
pd.read_excel(path, engine='xlrd')
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is the error?

Comment: the error: line 1278, in bof_error        
    raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: BOF not workbook/worksheet: op=0x0009 vers=0x0002 strm=0x000a build=0 year=0 
-> BIFF21